# Calling Through App with openUrl

Tags: ios, ios7

I've been trying to use the **openUrl** function is iOS to dial phone numbers from my app, but it's not going through, the numbers from the response have white spaces, and I've tried to remove it but when I **NSLog** it's not removing it

```
   (void)phone:(id)sender{
NSString *phone = [[information valueForKeyPath:@"place_detail"] objectForKey:@"phone"];
[phone stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSString *dial = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", phone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dial]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
[phone stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

With this:

```
phone = [phone stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to remove all forms of white space:

```
NSArray* words = [yourString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet :[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSString* nospacestring = [words componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

This is advantageous because it removes not only the space character.

Next just call with the following method:

```
NSString *value=@"your number";
NSURL *url = [[ NSURL alloc ] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",value]];
```

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];